# Error in adding trim parameter with tapply() and min()

Tags: r

I have a data frame with 4 columns (temperature, rain, month, yr) and ~7,000 rows.  I don't know a good way to actually post the data here?

As an exercise, I was using tapply to build a table where each row was a year, and each column was the minimum temperature for each month of that year.  I used

```
data <- read.table("temperatures.txt", header=T)
attach(data)
tapply(temperature,list(yr,month),min)
```

And that worked just fine.  I got

```
        1    2   3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10  11   12
1987 -6.8  3.0 2.8  8.3 10.5 12.5 14.3 15.3 13.5  9.5 1.8  2.8
1988  1.8  4.8 4.3  6.0 11.0 12.5 16.3 15.0 12.3  9.3 2.3  3.3
1989  2.3  3.8 6.0  2.8 13.3 11.5 18.0 17.5 16.0 12.5 4.8  2.8
1990  4.0  6.4 1.5  7.8 12.8 13.8 17.0 18.0 14.0 10.8 3.0  1.0
and so on
```

But then I tried to add the "trim" parameter for the min function.

```
tapply(temperature,list(yr,month),min, trim = 0.1)
```

And I now get

```
        1    2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11   12
1987 -6.8  0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1  0.1
1988  0.1  0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1  0.1
1989  0.1  0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1  0.1
```

What am I doing incorrectly?  Most of those yr/month combinations don't even have a temperature of 0.1 inthe data set....

Comment: there is no `trim` argument with `min`

Comment: Well that would explain it.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `trim` argument in `mean` and it is not there in `min`.  So, if we provide a new value, it would be taken to calculate the `min` as the usage of `min` is

> min(..., na.rm = FALSE)

the `...` can have `n` number of values and it can be named as well, so `trim` doesn't contribute anything here except the value itself

```
min(0, 5, -2, trim = 0.1) # minimum value is -2
#[1] -2
min(0, 5, 3, trim = 0.1) # minimum is 0
#[1] 0
min(0.2, 5, 3, trim = 0.1)
#[1] 0.1

min(0.5, hello =5, trim = 0.2, trimtrim = 0.4)
#[1] 0.2
```

---

The below example with `mtcars` were values for 'mpg' are all greater than 0.1, but it returns 0.1 due to this effect

```
tapply(mtcars$mpg, list(mtcars$cyl, mtcars$vs), function(x) min(x, trim = 0.1))
#   0   1
#4 0.1 0.1
#6 0.1 0.1
#8 0.1  NA
```